# CSS alignment: horizontal blocking?

Tags: css, alignment, block, padding, min

I am working on a CMS template and try to find out if this is possible at all. I was not able to find anything on the net, maybe I just used the wrong keywords.

---

Have this model given:

http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/4979/alignmentmockup.jpg

`<div> #1` is a fixed 'banner' container aligned left.

`<div> #2` is a another container with a fixed width. It is supposed to be centered using the whole site as measurement (scale #2) but shall not overlap with `<div> #1` (scale #1).

---

**Problem**: when the browser window is too small (e.g. resized, mobile browser), the container overlaps with the `<div> #1`. Depending on their z-index, one of them is on top of the other.

**Approach 1**: Both container on the same z-index. `<div> #2` has `margin:0 auto;`
*but* that does not stop them from overlapping.

**Approach 2**: Both styled `position: relative; float: left; z-index: 10`
*but* `<div> #2`does not align to the websites center anymore.

---

Since this is a resticted template back end I am working on, I cannot add additional containers as I want. I only have access to the portion of the HTML-file right between the `<body>` and the beginning of the websites functions. So I can only add separate `<div>`s (like `<div> #1`)  but cannot cascade them with the rest of the website (like `<div> #2`).

*Any hint for another approach appreciated!*

Comment: You shouldn't begin ID or CLASS names with a numeric value, always start with a letter! `#nr1` and `#nr2`. Also a live example or a complete example of your code would help greatly with your question.

Comment: Whoa, you're like me - but smaller...

Comment: @Kyle, no worries. I just named them like this in the mockup to make it easier to understand. Thanks for the nod though.
@Neuroflox - plain lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that CSS doesn't have min-margin that you could set on div2 with the width of div1. I remember reading an article about this not long ago and found a good solution by Ron Adair:

http://www.iamron.com/downloads/min-padding.html

The full article in which a more complex solution is presented. Ron then comments his easier way to get the same result:

http://buildinternet.com/2009/10/purely-css-faking-minimum-margins

Comment: Lovely, thanks Bazzz! Exactly the way I liky my work arounds ;)